# A good introductory book about differential calculus on commutative algebras?

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

Do you guys recommend a good introductory book about differential geometry over commutative algebras ? my current understanding of the subject is that all the differential calculus on a manifold can be reconstructed from the ring of smooth scalar functions on it with added derivations, ..etc. 
so we generalize this to reconstruct differential geometry out of any commutative ring which produces a kind of *commutative geometry*.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can read books about algebraic geometry, most will cover things like Kähler differentials.

Comment: I know nothing about the subject myself, but I think this must be the kind of book you're after: Jet Nestruev, *Smooth Manifolds and Observables* (Springer 2003). From the Preface: "the good old differential calculus is actually a special case of a much more general construction, which may be described as the *differential calculus over commutative algebras.*" There's a brief review [here](https://euro-math-soc.eu/review/smooth-manifolds-and-observables), and an appreciative mention [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley beautiful recommendation i downloaded it and it seems the one